# What is ->load(),->getData() in Magento and how does it work

Tags: database, magento-1, model, crud

```
$deal_m = Mage::getModel('dailydeals/deal')->load($deal_ids, 'deal_id');
$deal_m->getData()
```

I can understand this above code will get the values for deal_id=$deal_ids from the deal table.But I don't know the process or logic behind this `->load()`,`->getData()`.

Can any one please explain this process or suggest me any learning tutorials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the `load()` method is a read from the database.

- first parameter is the id
- second parameter is the column that will be used as the identifier

In your case and assuming that it is a flat entity, the first line corresponds to something like this:

```
select * from dailydeals_table where deal_id = $deal_ids;
```

NB: I'm not sure what you table name exactly is, it's probably different than `dailydeals_table`

The `getData()` method returns the retrieved values as an array.

Comment: Thank you.wherever in my controller is it possible to use load method to get value from database?

Comment: @mujas yes definitely possible.

Comment: thank you,is there any there any tutorials to reading regarding this?

Comment: @mujas I suggest you have a look at this post from Inchoo which explains the basics of loading and getting: http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-debugging/getting-things-in-magento-by-getmodel-and-getdata-methods/